# How to make horizontal lines thicker?

Tags: sectioning, rules, titlesec

I am customizing the section module following the tutorial here
http://blog.scribtex.com/how-to-write-a-latex-class-file-and-design-yo

How do I make the

```
  [\titlerule]                 % Inserts a horizontal line after the heading
```

thicker?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the optional argument of `\titlerule` to specify the rule height. Note that you'll have to wrap `\titlerule[<height>]` into braces if you're using it in the optional argument of `\titleformat`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
    {\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[{\titlerule[2pt]}]

\begin{document}

\section{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Just use something like `\titlerule[.8pt]`. The default is .4pt.

Comment: And for the width? Because default is \textwidth...

Comment: @FormlessCloud I'm sorry. No idea why I didn't see your comment at the time. Well, you could always somehow change the `\textwidth`, with a `minipage` or something. But for rules that have height *and* width, there is actually the `\rule` command: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Rules_and_Struts